# Can't access VS Code web build from source via remote linux machine

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm following the contributing doc to build VS Code from source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute

I built it in remote linux machine and try to access it from my laptop.

```bash
$cd vscode

$yarn

$./scripts/code-web.sh
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node build/lib/builtInExtensions.js
[16:49:01] Synchronizing built-in extensions...
[16:49:01] You can manage built-in extensions with the --builtin flag
[16:49:01] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug-companion@1.0.18 ✔︎
[16:49:01] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug@1.77.2 ✔︎
[16:49:01] [github] ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table@1.0.3 ✔︎
Done in 0.48s.
Starting @vscode/test-web: /home/ubuntu/vscode/node_modules/@vscode/test-web/out/index.js --host localhost --port 8080 --browserType none --sourcesPath /home/ubuntu/vscode
@vscode/test-web: 0.0.41
Serving VS Code sources from /home/ubuntu/vscode
Listening on http://localhost:8080
```

However, I can't access from my macOS, I used iptables to map it from 8080 to 5980, as the ubuntu in KVM:
[image]

However, it should works, since I can access it from the same machine using wget:

```bash
$ wget http://127.0.0.1:8080
--2023-04-14 16:49:46--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 396363 (387K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                        100%[=============================================================>] 387.07K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  

2023-04-14 16:49:46 (325 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [396363/396363]

ubuntu@theia01:~/todel$ cat index.html 
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <script>
                        performance.mark('code/didStartRenderer')
                </script>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

The iptable rule should work, since I tried to replace it with:

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

And got:
[image]